# Screenshot of window

Tags: winapi, screenshot, aero, aero-glass

I'm trying to take screenshots of all open windows, also the minimized ones. Currently I'm using this code:
http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/

But it doesn't work for minimized windows and the areas where there is a Glass effect since Vista like the explorer title bar are black. Can anyone help me out?

My objective is to create something similar to Flip 3D; it would be great if someone also knew something about how to create a live preview.

Comment: Don't understand the close vote here, how is it not programming related?

Comment: Found a great solution which allows live preview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969541%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Jon Seigel: Why are you taking the time to edit my question from last year just to remove the greeting? oO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the API that is used for the taskbar previews a.s.o.:

[DWM Thumbnail Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969541%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Pretty awesome, it even allows you to do live previews!

Answer (score 1):

For the glass effect areas: I think it doesn't work because those areas may be drawn with some strange DirectX method instead of normal GDI.

For the minimized windows problem: if a window is minimized, its DC isn't painted (conceptually, it doesn't even have a reason to exist); you should try to send to such windows a WM_PRINT message, asking them to paint themselves on the DC you'll provide them. The problem with this approach is that not all the windows handle correctly WM_PRINT.

Comment: `WM_PRINT` generally doesn't work for minimized windows, because the window doesn't have a normal size when minimized.